# Python, what is the object method of built-in id()?

Tags: python, built-in, python-internals

In Python:

- `len(a)` can be replaced by `a.__len__()`
- `str(a)` or `repr(a)` can be replaced by `a.__str__()` or `a.__repr__()`
- `==` is `__eq__`, `+` is `__add__`, etc.

Is there similar method to get the `id(a)` ? If not, is there any workaround to get an unique id of a python object without using `id()` ?

---

**edit:** additional question: if not ? is there any reason not to define a `__id__()` ?

Comment: You cannot override the behavior of `id`.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: No since id represents the emplacement of the object in memory.

Comment: @segfolt In CPython, yes, but this is not guaranteed by the Python language itself.

Comment: @BrenBarn I'm trying to redefine its behavior or mimic it, add some feature to it, in the end i want to have a unique id. More importantly, I want to understand how it works. For example the code is run in a sandbox without builtin methods, i don't want to depend on it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, this behavior cannot be changed.  `id()` is used to get *"an integer (or long integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime"* ([source](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id)).  No other special meaning is given to this integer (in CPython it is the address of the memory location where the object is stored, but this cannot be relied upon in portable Python).

Since there is no special meaning for the return value of `id()`, it makes no sense to allow you to return a different value instead.

Further, while you could guarantee that `id()` would return unique integers for your *own* objects, you *could not possibly* satisfy the global uniqueness constraint, since your object cannot possibly have knowledge of all other living objects.  It would be possible (and likely) that one of your special values clashes with the identity of another object alive in the runtime.  This would not be an acceptable scenario.

If you need a return value that has some special meaning then you should define a method where appropriate and return a useful value from it.

Comment: I think id() is quite unique globally... as it's the memory address of the object. if another object has the same value, it should be the reference to the existing object... or else I misunderstood yours. If it's not for the purpose of "unique identification" why should id() exist in the first place? Other than that I believe I can neither redefine its behavior or mimic its behavior in any other way.

Comment: @w00d The return value from `id()` does not have to be the memory address of the object.  It is on CPython, because it is convenient to use the address as the id since it is guaranteed to be unique.  But CPython is not the only Python implementation, and an implementation of Python can use *whatever value it wants* for `id()`, as long as two objects alive at the same time do not have the same id, and the id for one particular object never changes. Sequentially-numbered IDs would be just as valid an implementation.

Comment: And yes, `id()` can be used to verify that two variables reference exactly the same object.  That is one possible use for identity values, and yes, unique identification is *exactly* why `id()` exists.  Your original question was about providing a custom method to provide a substitute value when you call `id()` on such an object, and my answer explains why this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

An object isn't aware of its own name (it can have many), let alone of any unique ID it has associated with it. So - in short - no. The reasons that `__len__` and co. work is that they are bound to the object already - an object is not bound to its ID.

Comment: An object can carry around *a* unique ID just fine (and the unique ID assigned by `id()` is completely unrelated to the names referring to the object, so I don't see how that's relevant). The language just doesn't provide a write access to that particular ID (and mandates an unusual way of reading from it). And objects are, in fact, bound to their `id()` in any meaning of the word that comes to mind -- it's constant and unique for the entire lifetime of the object.

Comment: @delnan yes - but what I'm saying is that the object isn't aware of whatever ID it has been assigned (nor does it need to be). The ID will be made at the time of object creation/assignment in whatever way the implementation sees fit. The OP is asking if there is an equivalent `__magic__` method - of which there *is not* as that is handled at a lower level so there is no way an object *by itself* knows what its ID is...

Comment: Half of what you're saying is confusing unrelated issues, and the other half is using low-level implementation details to argue about high-level capabilities. Why couldn't there be a `object.__id__` that returns the implementation's ID but can be overriden? It's similar for other things, such as attribute access.

Comment: yeah.. i wonder the same thing as @delnan why shouldn't be a `__id__()` to override ?

Comment: There definitely *should* not be such a thing (has absolutely no use, has great potential for screwing things up, makes a pretty fundamental operation more complex). However, there *could* be, which is what we're debating here.

Comment: @delnan Indeed: the other thing to consider is that `x is y` needn't be implemented as `id(x) == id(y)` so being able to override it probably wouldn't even work as intended anyway (plus as you mention - it's just providing too many ways to make things go pear shaped). Maybe the core dev's just decided that actually there was no legitimate use for it...

Comment: @JonClements This lack of guarantee is partially because it doesn't matter (you can't override either). If one could override it, that question could be settled (for `+` it's precisely defined which magic methods are called) or ignored (if you do weird things in `__hash__` and `__eq__`, hash tables do weird things too). Yes, it's currently not done and that's a good thing. No, unlike you previously implied, that's not because it's impossible -- it just has consequences for other features. That's true for every decision.